# Trouble with Retina & CSS background image

Tags: css, retina-display

I'm developing a site the owner wants private until launch.

The owner is on OSX, and I am on Windows.

On Windows, the site looks fine, like this:
[image]

Note the blue banner with animals - the animals are displayed in full, and this banner is produced by CSS:

```
.ribbon-container {
    height: 78px;
    background: url(images/mesopotamia_shadow.jpg) center bottom repeat-x;
}
```

From another Q&A, I've found some CSS to potentially solve a problem the owner had on OSX. On her computer, the blue banner doesn't display properly. It looks something like this:

[image]

It is produced by the CSS:

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 
    .ribbon-container {
        height: 78px;
        background-size: 552px 78px;
        background: url('images/mesopotamia_shadow-x2.jpg') center bottom repeat-x;
    }
}
```

Note the image displayed is larger than on Windows. `images/mesopotamia_shadow-x2.jpg` (1104 x 156) [click here for the image](http://i112.photobucket.com/albums/n180/SRD001/screenshots/mesopotamia_shadow.jpg) is twice the height and width of `images/mesopotamia_shadow.jpg` (552 x 78) [click here for the image](http://i112.photobucket.com/albums/n180/SRD001/screenshots/mesopotamia_shadow.jpg). Is this correct or not?

Is the CSS correct?

Comment: Normally everything is alright but, try to kick that min-res thing
and tell me what happen : 
`only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try:

```
.ribbon-container {
    height: 78px;
    background: url(images/mesopotamia_shadow.jpg) center bottom repeat-x;
    background-size:contain;
}
```

Which should make the image fit within it's container.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but I am assuming you are asking how to make the background-image fill the div, and not get cut off. You can do it by changing the background size like `background-size:auto 100%;`:

```css
div{
    height:200px;
    background:url(http://i112.photobucket.com/albums/n180/SRD001/screenshots/mesopotamia_shadow.jpg);
    background-size:auto 100%;
    resize:both;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Jacob-Gray/pen/NGEJPE)
Or, in your code:

```
.ribbon-container {
    height: 78px;
    background: url(images/mesopotamia_shadow.jpg) center bottom repeat-x;
    background-size:auto 100%;
}
```

In the above demo's the image fills as much space as possible, no `@media` queries needed.